# Filtering Lines from Response Text

Tags: python

```
> r=request.get(myHttp)
> myText=r.text
```

There is Some portion of text I wanat to filter out from myText. Suppose My Text is like

```
> <html> <body>
> <h1>WantedLIne number one
      Wanter Line Number TWO
      UnWanter Line </h1>
<p> Match Pick This Line Please.</p>
 <p> Does Not Match donet Pick </p>
 <p>Match One More Line to Pick</p>
> 
> <p>My favorite color is <del>blue</del> red.</p>
> 
> </body> </html>
```

I wana to filter out some String such that,

> All lines between '`<p> Match`' and  '`</p>`'
>
> Two Line which follows '`<h1>`'
>
> There would be multiple Lines to pick .

**Expected output is**

- WantedLIne number one
- Wanter Line Number TWO
- Pick This Line Please.
- One More Line to Pick

Comment: Please repeat [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) from the
[intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).  This is not a site where you get to post a problem and get back working code.

Answer (score 0):

You can try work with lxml and xpath.

```
from lxml import etree # you may need to pip install lxml

html  = "<the content of your HTML>"
tree = etree.HTML(html)
p_nodes_target = tree.xpath("//p[starts-with(normalize-space(text()),'Match')]")
first_p_value = "" if p_node_target is None or len(p_node_target) == 0 else p_nodes_target[0].text
```

The value of first_p_value should be - Match Pick This Line Please. You can then replace "Match" with empty text.

in fact for the HTML code you provide, regular expression also works, but for more complex HTML pages, XPath is better.

learn XPath: https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xpath_syntax.asp

Comment: Thanks, Would this take 2 Lines following  '<h1>'  ? And At times the text is not HTML, hope the etree.HTML would help if  the response is LogFiles or JSON